# Metric components transformation under change of coordinates

Tags: homework-and-exercises, differential-geometry, metric-tensor, coordinate-systems, vector-fields

I have been studying Lie derivatives and some applications. While searching the web I found a reference with the following statement:

> For a general Riemannian manifold $M$, take a tangent vector field $k=k^\mu \partial _\mu$ and consider the infinitesimal coordinate transformation,
> $$
> x^\mu \to x^\mu + \alpha k^\mu~,
> $$
> where $|\alpha| \ll 1$. Then it is possible to find that the metric components
> $g_{\mu \nu}$ transform as
> $$
> g_{\mu \nu} \to g_{\mu \nu} + \alpha(\partial_\mu k_\nu + \partial _\nu k_\mu + k^\sigma \partial _\sigma g_{\mu\nu} ) +O(\alpha^2)~.
> $$

Now, how does the author get this? Does the author just uses the usual transformation law for a $(0,2)$-type tensor? This does not seem to be the case, since he finds so many terms. Moreover, I do not know the inverse transformation, so I wouldn't be able to apply it. Can somebody help me?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The metric being a rank $(0,2)$ tensor transforms under general coordinate transformations $x^\mu \to x'^\mu(x)$ as
$$
g'_{\mu\nu} (x') = \frac{ \partial x^\rho}{ \partial x'^\mu } \frac{ \partial x^\sigma }{ \partial x'^\nu } g_{\rho\sigma} (x) 
$$

Now set $x'^\mu (x) = x^\mu + \alpha k^\mu(x)$ in the above expression and take a limit of small $\alpha$. You should then get
$$
g'_{\mu\nu}(x) = g_{\mu\nu}(x) - \alpha ( g_{\mu\rho} \partial_\nu k^\rho + g_{\nu\rho} \partial_\mu k^\rho + k^\rho \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu} ) + {\cal O} (\alpha^2) 
$$

The above is the correct version of the transformation. I believe you have gotten it wrong in the question (v1)

Comment: This must be a really stupid question but what do you mean substitute in the expression?Make a Taylor expansion?

Comment: BTW, to be clear, the inverse transformation is $x^\mu = x'^\mu - a k^\mu + O(a^2)$.

Comment: @PML - I mean, substitute the expression for $x'^\mu$ that I've written down into the first equation and _then_ do a Taylor expansion in $\alpha$.

Comment: @Prahar why do you have $\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}$ instead of $\partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}'$ when you Taylor expand?

Comment: I write $\partial_\rho g'_{\mu\nu} = \partial_\rho g_{\mu\nu}  + {\cal O}( \alpha)$.

Comment: Is it the same thing to write the expression as covariant derivatives rather than partial derivatives. Because I’ve been told to prove the variation as covariant derivatives of variation of coordinates.